# Error connecting to MySQL database (No such host is known)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin

While using the following code to connect to my SQL database:

```
MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=vipervenom.net.mysql; userid=vipervenom_net_userinfo; password=PASSGOESHERE; database=vipervenom_net_userinfo;"
```

it prompts an error saying

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> No such host is known.

I've been looking for hours to find an answer to this, but even though my host and login information is correct, it gives me that error. Take a look at the picture for login information -->
[image: DATABASE LOGIN INFORMATION]

The entire source code:

```
MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=vipervenom.net.mysql; userid=vipervenom_net_userinfo; password=PASS GOES HERE; database=vipervenom_net_userinfo;"

    Try

        MySqlConnection.Open()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    Dim MyAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * From Users WHERE email='" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND password='" & TextBox2.Text & "';"
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand

    command.Connection = MySqlConnection
    command.CommandText = sqlquery
    MyAdapter.SelectCommand = command
    Dim Mydata As MySqlDataReader
    Mydata = command.ExecuteReader

    If Mydata.HasRows = 0 Then

        MsgBox("Wrong login information!")

    Else

        MsgBox("Login Successful! :D")
    End If
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the database on the same server as the code? It could be that the SQL server is not configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: The database is hosted by a domain hoster. The code is on my own computer in a software.

Comment: Are you sure that they allow direct remote connections to this database?

Comment: Hey Steve, I contacted the customer support and their response was "Sorry a remote access to the database (e.g. from your computer) is not possible. You can only connect to the database via phpMyAdmin (in your control panel) or via your webspace (PHP connection string) , or via SSH in terminal."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, `vipervenom.net.mysql` is not, and cannot be, a valid hostname, your hosting provider's statements to the contrary notwithstanding.

There aren't any hostnames ending in `.mysql` because that is not a valid top level domain name.

It's *possible* your hosting provider has an internal domain naming service handling `.mysql` as a TLD. But you won't be able to use that hostname from outside their network.

Ask your hosting provider what hostname to use for your MySQL server from outside their network.